# Removing Firefox Addon prefs when a user uninstalls

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox addon and one thing i'm unsure on is how to remove user preferences related to my addon when the user uninstalls it. The preferences get set, and if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the preferences are all still there. Some settings also relate to a first time install, so that breaks if the user has installed it previously.

Is there something I can setup that will be called when a user uninstalls, or a process to remove preferences on uninstall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [this page](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Recipe_Book/Extensions_and_Core/Uninstall) which shows you how to register an observer to get the right events.  Note that it's not always 100% reliable, but there should [be a way to do this in Firefox 3.7 (Gecko 1.9.3)](http://www.oxymoronical.com/blog/2009/03/Letting-add-ons-perform-work-during-install-and-uninstall).

Comment: This is quite outdated, Can you explain how to do It today?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this. Addons are simply deleted off by the browser and not told that they will be uninstalled. You could provide a 'Restore Factory Settings' button somewhere on your add on GUI.

Comment: fair enough. I had a feeling that might be the case since if it let the addon know it was being deleted that could leave the door open for it to do something malicious. Thanks

Comment: This isn't true - it is in fact possible to do this, although it isn't always 100% reliable.

Comment: This is not true. You can register a listener to a shutdown event as follows: `exports.onUnload = function(options, callbacks) { MyPlugin.onUnload(); }`